# Problema con interrupciones en hibridacion en C y Ensamblador

Tags: c, ensamblador

Tengo un problema quiero utilizar interrupciones de ensamblador con C pero me dice

> Excepción no controlada en 0x009B1F01 en ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación 0xFFFFFFFF.

el codigo es el siguiente

```
long random() {
    int R = 0;
    _asm {
        MOV AH, 2CH
        INT 21H
        MOV AH,DH
        MOV R, EAX
    }

    return R;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_asm` es exclusivo de Microsoft, así que entiendo que estás programando en Windows.

Bajo Windows no está permitido utilizar las interrupciones a la ligera, como sucedía con MS-DOS.

La conversión más sencilla pasaría por usar `time(NULL)`

```
long random() {
  return time(NULL);
}
```